# OroCommerce: How to add new fields to Order LineItems?

Tags: orocommerce

Using Entities Management I've extended Order Line Item  adding some new fields that I need, updated schema and etc, new fields appeared in the line items grid on the order view page, but nothing was added to the line items grid in order edit mode.. I did the same to the Shopping List Line Items and new fields appeared both on view/edit and Add Line Item Form, so whats wrong with order and how to add new fields there?

Upd:
Looking to the order edit templates I see that there is no fields definition in template and eachline item fields are rendered via form sections. So the only working solution I found is to change oro source code for the **Oro\Bundle\OrderBundle\Form\Type\OrderLineItemType**  adding sections for my fields

```
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        $this->getSectionProvider()->addSections(
            \get_class($this),
            [
                'start_date' => ['data' => ['startDate' => []], 'order' => 5],
                'end_date' =>   ['data' => ['endDate' => []], 'order' => 6],
            ]
        );
    }
```

and they appeared in order edit. But its unacceptable to modify oro source code so I created my custom `class CustomOrderLineItemType extends OrderLineItemType`
and added migration to replace existing formtype for OrderLineItem.. and its not working, seems that oro still uses internal class, why?

```
class UpdateOrderLineItemFormType implements Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema, QueryBag $queries)
    {
        $queries->addQuery(
            new UpdateEntityConfigEntityValueQuery(
                OrderLineItem::class,
                'form',
                'form_type',
                CustomOrderLineItemType::class
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the table in a form by overriding the template, where it's rendered.
See the documentation on how to find the template using twig inspector and how to override it in OroCommerce:

https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/back-office/templates/

To extend the existing form with the new field you can write a form type extension:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: I dont see possibility to add new fields via template extension, please check updated first post

Comment: I extended the answer too. You can write a form type extesion